# How to check creation of two new files in bash and perform action?

Tags: shell-script

I have written a script which will check if a single new file is created and perform the action. However I want to perform that action if 'two' new files are created. Below is the script :

```
old_count=1
new_count=`ls /var/tmp/juniors/vaibhav/ | wc -l`

if [ "$new_count" -gt "$old_count" ]; then
        opcmsg a=test o=final msg_g=OpC_CRF msg_t=testing sev=minor
fi

$old_count=$new_count
```

Can anyone help me in modification of this script so that action is performed only after 2 new files are created and not one ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ "$new_count" -gt "$((old_count+1))" ]; then
```

Was it so hard?